# How do I create a template that allows dynamic index alias in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to follow this [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/faking-it.html) using elasticsearch 2.4 where multiple tenant data can be put into one index but by using alias and routes I can search an aliased index and only retrieve information from one particular tenant.

Briefly, I could have an index filled with widget doc types under the index **search_widgets**. but the template would create an alias as I enter in widget docs based on the value of the user-id. If the widget type doc has user-id = 1 it would create an index alias search_widget-1. If searched with a get-all on that index it would return widgets docs that has user-id = 1 as a field in it.

Here's a incomplete example of how it think it should work

**PUT** /search_widgets

```js
{
  "search_widgets": {
    "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 2
    },
    "mappings": {
      "widget": {
        "properties": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "@version": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "active": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "user-id": {
            "type": "number",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "created_date": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "updated_date": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "aliases": {
      "widget": {
        "routing": "search_widget_*",
        "filter": {
          "term": {
            "user-id": "*"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```